# Create a dataframe with objects containing single values

Tags: r

I have the following numeric objects:

```
a1<-12 
a2<-10 
a3<-8
a4<-7
a5<-21
a6<-34
```

And I would love to have them as a column in a database. I can easily do:

```
df<-data.frame(value=c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6))
```

but I would love to be able to do it as a sequence. I've tryed a few things, like:

```
df<-data.frame(value=c(paste0("a",1:6)))
```

or

```
df<-value=c(get(paste0("a",1:6)))
```

But none of them put the values into the dataframe.

What is the right approach here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are getting multiple objects, you should use `mget()` instead.

```
df <- data.frame(value = unlist(mget(paste0("a", 1:6))))

   value
a1    12
a2    10
a3     8
a4     7
a5    21
a6    34
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `map` and `get` in r.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(values = (map(paste0("a", 1:6), get) %>% unlist))
df
```

Output:

```
  values
1     12
2     10
3      8
4      7
5     21
6     34
```

NOTE: You'll have to use `dplyr` to use the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! This one works too!